# Why the Screen background black while hiding action bar?

Tags: android

When I hide the action bar the background color of screen changes to black why this happens? please help me. I am hiding the action bar in My Manifest file.below i have my manifest file code.

```
<activity
        android:name=".UserEventsCreation"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_user_events_creation"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
```

Comment: try hiding action bar in your individual activities.

Comment: what do you mean please?

Comment: try to remove android:label="x";

Comment: getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().hide();

Comment: try @PräTîkTank answer for each screen you want to hide actionbar.

Answer (score 0):

`@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` references a dark theme.
For the light theme use `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` instead.

Comment: @Usman you're welcome. You can also [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so people know easyly that it worked.